# Using JavaScript/AJAX to Insert Row into Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, sql-insert

I have a button that can be clicked that will bring up a popup box with one textfield. Whenever, I enter something and click "Add", I want it to be inserted into my database.

Currently, when I click "Add", it will insert into the DB, but it will not read the value that was entered. Therefore, a null value is simply entered. I get no errors that I can see, however in my JavaScript I do a `console.log(type + " : " + value);` and it returns `sku_group-0 :` in the logs. I also do a `console.log(dict)` and the output in the log is `Object {}` so it doesn't look like the entered value is being logged. I also am getting a successful `row inserted` message in the logs too so I would definitely think that it is just a matter of being able to get the values to be read.

So my question is how can I get it to read the value and successfully enter it into the database.

HTML of Add button:

```
<button class="create-user" id="insertButton">Add Group</button>
```

HTML of Popup Box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Group">
  <p class="validateTips">Please Add a Group</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>        

      <label for="sku_group">SKU Group</label>
      <input type="text" name="group" id="group" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">


      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      sku_group = $( "#group" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( sku_group ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }


   function addGroup() {

      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( sku_group, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid SKU Group name" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#skuTable tbody tr td" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $tr.each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).html();
        console.log(type + " : " + value);

      switch (type) {
        case "group":
            dict["SKU Group"] = value;
        break;
        }
    });
        $( "#skuTable tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-group.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });

}

      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Group": addGroup,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addGroup();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });

  });
```

insert-group.php script:

```
<?php

  $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO SKU_Group_Dim ([SKU Group]) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($SKU_Group));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: INSERT INTO doesn't return the inserted values. Change the php and create a second mysql request to get the new data. Think of simultanious entries (unique identifiers).

Answer (score 1):

Modify the statement

```
sku_group = $( "#group" )
```

with

```
sku_group = $( "#group" ).val();
```

This should solve your problem.

Edit to Save TxtValue into Database...

```
 $(function () {
        var TxtValue = $("#group").val();

        $("#submit").click(function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
            if(!TxtValue){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert-group.php",
                    data: {[agrumentName]: TxtValue},
                    success: function(e){
                        console.log(e);
                        console.log("Row Insrerted");
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                console.log("Cannot Insert Null Value");
            }
        })
    })
```

replace [agrumentName] with your server function argument.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am now getting an error that `o.val` is not a function in my `function checkRegexp`

Comment: when you are already passing value from '$("#group").val()' you need not to apply val() to o, you can directly go with o rather than o.val()

Comment: I got rid of the `.val()` after `o` and got another error that `o.addClass` was not a function, so for the sake of testing purposes I commented it out and it is still not working. Still inserting a NULL value.

Comment: you trying to add value of #group textbox or you are trying to add table tr td values, coz in add group function you are looping through table td and trying to get value. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I want to add the value of the #group textbox in my popup box

Comment: See my edit, this simple function should serve your purpose to insert textvalue into database.

Comment: what do you mean by server function argument

Comment: on your backend their should be some function which accepts this value as argument, replace that argument name here, atwhich you need this ajax call to direct pointer

Comment: Not getting any errors but still inserting null values...I'm not sure this is the way to go....I've taken a lot of code from a previous program that I completed which had an Add Row function so i would think it would be pretty similar to that. I dont think the AJAX needs changed at all. My other program had textfields like this one and the AJAX looks exactly the same and also with no `("#submit").click(function (e)`...im thinking its gotta just be something minor like it usually is in programming

Comment: I don't have any idea about your backend, but for client side my example working perfectly for me.. you can check logging value of TxtValue into console if you getting value on submit click, it its I doubt then you will need to check backend code...